# Method calling method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have some asp.net mvc methods which has lots of common lines.

So I tried to write one common metod to eliminate code reuse, but I failed to receive result. Can you show where is the problem?

// Initial Code:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id) {
                if (id == null)
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                if (product == null)
                    return HttpNotFound();             
                return View(product);
            }
```

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(product);
        }
```

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete (int? id) {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(product);
        }
```

// Final Code:

```
public void Details(int? id) {
            Common(id);
        }
[HttpGet]
public void Edit(int? id) {
            Common(id);
        }
[HttpGet]
public void Delete (int? id) {
            Common(id);
        }

public ActionResult Common(int? Id) {
            if (Id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            Product product = db.Products.Find(Id);
            if (product == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(product);
        }
```

Blank screen on output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have accidentally or intentionally changed the callers to return `void`. The callers' signatures should not change. They should still return `ActionResult`s:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id) {
    return Common(id);
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {
    return Common(id);
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete (int? id) {
    return Common(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir: Works perfect!!! Initially I also tried to use ActionResult, but did not write return keyword. And it gave syntax error. Now everything works!!!

Comment: Sweeper's answer is correct, however I'm not so sure that the code you have right now is good - it's basically doing the same thing over and over again when it's suppose to do different things - I mean, a method called Details should do one thing, a method called Edit should do a different thing, and a method called  Delete should do a third thing - The current code structure suggests otherwise.